# SQL Select where one field equals another, but with an additional character in the middle

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, substring, where-in

I've got 2 tables of invoice data and I am trying to use one of them to update the other, based on a PO Number.

```
UPDATE Reconcile
SET Reconcile.Customer = Invoices.Customer,
Reconcile.InvoiceNum = Invoices.InvoiceNumber
FROM Invoices
WHERE Reconcile.PONumber = Invoices.PONum
```

Simple enough. My problem is that the PO Numbers don't always match perfectly. Some of them have a dash in them. So instead of just **FM000112345678** to match on, I might have **FM0001-12345678**, but I still need to match them. I've been testing some SUBSTRING queries in a SELECT with no luck.

```
SELECT * FROM Reconcile AS A
WHERE A.PONumber IN (
SELECT DISTINCT PONum
FROM Invoices AS B
WHERE (B.PONum LIKE (SUBSTRING(A.PONumber,0,5) + '%'))
AND B.PONum LIKE ('%' + SUBSTRING(REVERSE(A.PONumber),0,8)))
```

This returns no results. I tried with CHARINDEX.

```
SELECT * FROM Reconcile AS A
WHERE A.PONumber IN (
SELECT DISTINCT PONum
FROM Invoices AS B
WHERE (B.PONum LIKE (SUBSTRING(A.PONumber,0,5) + '%'))
AND B.PONum LIKE (RIGHT(A.PONumber,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(A.PONumber))-1)))
```

Still no results. I am obviously missing something.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the issue is just hyphens, you can use `replace()`:

```
WHERE REPLACE(Reconcile.PONumber, '-', '') = REPLACE(Invoices.PONum, '-' ,'')
```

Comment: Jeez. It seems so obvious now. Thank you for that!